# Top align text inside TextBlock

Tags: wpf

Consider this XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="80" Width="200" Height="100" Grid.Row="1" Background="DodgerBlue" Foreground="White" Text="Test"/>
</Grid>
```

It will show very clearly that there are a lot of spacing above the text. Is it possible to get rid of that space so that the capital T in "Test" starts at the top left corner of the textblock?

It does not have to be a textblock.
It cannot be solved using negative margins.
It cannot be solved by stretching the font.

If the text is moved inside the textblock, or the textblock itself is resized doesn't matter. I just need the solution to have no spacing above the highest letter in the text (here the capital T).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two nice solutions I have found some time ago on StackOverflow:

1. Add padding to the TextBlock.
2. Place TextBlock inside a border and let the border care about alignment.

Play around with them and you should get what you want.

edit: These are of course workarounds. There is no direct way to do vertical content alignment in a TextBlock that I know of.

Comment: The border did the trick - it is not a pretty solution, but a workaround to deal with the missing vertical alignment in the textblock. Thanks.